# how to make script recognize scope in template node-red?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, node-red

i have this code in node-red.i want to add template node to it. i think the script does not know what the scope is.when i log a value by jquery it returns null.and i get this error:can not read property innerhtml of null.and i log the scope and all the id s are null.i do not know how to fix it.it is necessary .please help.

the data i am sending to it is something like this: msg.payload = "{"power":[12,14,13,14],"switch":["ON"]}"

```
<div class="bg">
<div id="container" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="plan col-md-4">
            <h3 id="voltage1"><span class="status1">OFF</span></h3>
            <div class="Amp">Amp</div>
            <ul>
                <li><b>P1:</b></li>
                <li><b>P2:</b></li>
                <li><b>P3:</b></li>
                <li><b>N:</b></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="plan col-md-4">
            <h3 id="voltage2"><span class="status2">OFF</span></h3>
            <div class="Amp">Amp</div>
            <ul>
                <li><b>P1:</b></li>
                <li><b>P2:</b></li>
                <li><b>P3:</b></li>
                <li><b>N:</b></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="plan col-md-4">
            <h3 id="voltage3"><span class="status3">OFF</span></h3>
            <div class="Amp">Amp</div>
            <ul>
                <li><b>P1:</b></li>
                <li><b>P2:</b></li>
                <li><b>P3:</b></li>
                <li><b>N:</b></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="plan col-md-4">
            <h3 id="voltage4"><span class="status4">OFF</span></h3>
            <div class="Amp">Amp</div>
            <ul>
                <li><b>P1:</b></li>
                <li><b>P2:</b></li>
                <li><b>P3:</b></li>
                <li><b>N:</b></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="plan col-md-4">
            <h3 id="voltage5"><span class="status5">OFF</span></h3>
            <div class="Amp">Amp</div>
            <ul>
                <li><b>P1:</b></li>
                <li><b>P2:</b></li>
                <li><b>P3:</b></li>
                <li><b>N:</b></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="plan col-md-4">
            <h3 id="voltage6"><span class="status6">OFF</span></h3>
            <div class="Amp">Amp</div>
            <ul>
                <li><b>P1:</b></li>
                <li><b>P2:</b></li>
                <li><b>P3:</b></li>
                <li><b>N:</b></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (scope) {
    (function (scope) {
        function blinker() {
            $('span').fadeOut(500);
            $('span').fadeIn(500);
        }

        setInterval(blinker, 1000);
        scope.$watch('msg', function (msg) {
            var data = JSON.parse(msg.payload)
            console.log(scope)
            for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
                document.getElementById('#voltage' + i).innerHTML = "Voltage :" + data.power[i]
                if (data.switch[i] == 'ON') {
                    $('.status' + i).css("color", "green");
                    document.getElementsByClassName('.status' + i).innerHTML = 'ON'
                }
            }
        })
    })(scope)
})
```

Comment: Which template node? The core node or the Dashboard UI?

Comment: Please update the question with an example of the data you are passing into this template...

Comment: @hardillb Dashboard UI.i am using html element

Comment: @SteveR it has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dashboard already uses Angular widgets, models, and logic to render msg.payload information into the browser's DOM. Instead of trying to also manipulate HTML elements using JQuery, it's much simpler to pass an array of switch data objects into a single  container, using `ng-repeat` to create as many divs as necessary to show all the switches.

For instance, if you have these 3 sets of data in one `msg.payload` array:

```
[
  {
    "Switch": "ON",
    "Voltage": 117.5,
    "P1": 2.34,
    "P2": 3.45,
    "P3": 1.23,
    "N": 0.12
  },
  {
    "Switch": "OFF",
    "Voltage": 0,
    "P1": 0.02,
    "P2": 0.03,
    "P3": 0.12,
    "N": 0
  },
  {
    "Switch": "ON",
    "Voltage": 125,
    "P1": 0.34,
    "P2": 0.45,
    "P3": 0.23,
    "N": 0.25
  }
]
```

you can just pass it directly to a `ui_template` node, with this Angular code:

```
<style>
    span.ON { color: green; }
    span.OFF { color: red; }
</style>

<div class="bg">
<div id="container" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="row in msg.payload">
        <div class="plan col-md-4">
            <h3>
                {{$index+1}}.
                <span ng-class="row.Switch">{{row.Switch}}</span>
                <span ng-if="row.Switch == 'ON'">
                    Voltage : {{row.Voltage}}
                </span>
            </h3>
            <div class="Amp">Amp</div>
            <ul>
                <li><b>P1: </b>{{row.P1}}</li>
                <li><b>P2: </b>{{row.P2}}</li>
                <li><b>P3: </b>{{row.P3}}</li>
                <li><b>N: </b>{{row.N}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

to render this:

[image: angular template output]

No need to mess with `scope.$watch()` or create 7 nearly identical sections of html elements that need to be manipulated using JQuery...

Any time the state of one of the switches is updated, just resend the entire array of data -- Angular does the heavy lifting of updating the DOM to match your data, and will even reuse existing elements, or insert/update/delete them as necessary.

Comment: thanks a lot.but I want to have my boxes in different positions.is it possible in ng-repeat?

Comment: Well, the "boxes" of data have been built by the Angular `ng-repeat` logic -- now it's just a matter of styling them (using css to set widths, heights, positions, display type, color).

Comment: how?can you tell me ?

Comment: Not without a LOT more information about (and maybe pictures of) what you want it to look like...

Comment: http://skymics.com/Energy/sampleschematic.jpg see this picture.i want my 6 boxes go on the 6 vertical lines above the picture.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218885/how-to-give-different-padding-styles-to-ng-repeat-elements  @SteveR this is my code.